# SQL trying to select all columns instead of a few

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter, datatables

I am having a weird issue here..
I am using codeigniter for PHP and I am using a library called datatables. You can find it on this link https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/wiki/Function-Reference
Anyways I have the following query in the following structure..

```
 <?php

public function GetQuery(){

 $this->datatables->select('tablessc.Name As region,p.name As name,tabled.test As test,
                                  MAX(CASE WHEN p.id= p.cid and flavor = 2  THEN \'Pass\' ELSE \'Fail\' end) as \'Pass\'
                                  ')
                          ->from('drinks p');
                          $this->datatables->join('tableb ', 'tableb.id=p.pid','inner');
                          $this->datatables->join('tablec','tablec.TerritoryId=tablec.TerritoryId','inner');
                          $this->datatables->join('tabled','tablec.AccountId=tablec.AccountId','inner');
                          $this->datatables->join('tables','d.AccountId = tabless.AccountId ','inner');
                          $this->datatables->join('tablessc','tablesc.Code = p.region and sc.CodeGroup =\'Region\'','inner');

                          $this->datatables->where('region >','0');
                          $this->datatables->where('p.location','0');

                          $this->datatables->group_by('tablessc.Name');
                          $this->datatables->group_by('p.id');
                          $this->datatables->group_by('p.name');
                          $this->datatables->group_by('atabled.test');

echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
?>
```

This is the error i get

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Column 'country' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.


SELECT * 
FROM FROM drinks p 
INNER JOIN tableb ON tableb.id=p.pid 
INNER JOIN tablec ON tablec.TerritoryId=tablec.TerritoryId 
INNER JOIN tabled ON tablec.AccountId=tablec.AccountId 
INNER JOIN tables ON d.AccountId = tabless.AccountId 
INNER JOIN tablessc ON tablesc.Code = p.region 
    and sc.CodeGroup ='Region' 
WHERE region > '0' 
    AND p.location = '0' 
GROUP BY tablessc.Name
    ,p.id
    ,p.name
    ,atabled.test
```

THe problem is that why is it trying to select all columns when I only want to select that columns I am asking. The reason I am getting the error(aggregate function) is because its trying to select all columns

Also note if I was to put this query in the same structure on microsoft sql server I dont get an error

Comment: are `fourth` from the error msg and `thirdvalue` from the query the same name in reality?

Comment: fourth is just a column from 'sometable' I am not using it at all for this query.The reason why is showing in the error is because of the select * 
.FYI, I am just using arbitrary column names here. but its the same structure from my real query. The problem is that I don't understand why is it showing select * instead of select somevalue,anothervalue,thirdvalue, ....in my error message
It seems really odd

Comment: looks like `"somevalue,anothervalue,thirdvalue",MAX(CASE WHEN someid = 5 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end) as 'Test')` should actually be `'somevalue,anothervalue,thirdvalue,MAX(CASE WHEN someid = 5 THEN "Y" ELSE "N" end) as "Test")'` based on the link you posted but i have no exp with codeigniter

Comment: actually most of the double quotes look like they should be single quotes.

Comment: I think you might be right about the single quotes. I am getting another error but its not doing select *

Comment: another issue microsoft sql server accepts 'Y' not "Y" how can i fix that?

Comment: just fyi even with single quotes i am still having the same issue with select * from sometable

Comment: can you output exactly what is being passed to SQL server?

Comment: i just updated my question when i try to call the function GetQuery i get that error

Comment: clearly the from clause isnt working, does having `$this->datatables->from('drinks p');` change the error message?  Try simplifying the select list, take out the aggregate and the aliases and see if it still errors out.

Comment: if i run this query on the ide it works good. this is just really strange..

Comment: I feel like its ignoring the whole $this->datatables->select function

Comment: thats why i said try changing your select and see what happens, make it simpler.

Comment: oh yeah if i take the aggregate functions MAX and the group_by function it works

Comment: I would change the question to be more of how to use an aggregate through this, or read up on more examples, now that you've narrowed down your issue.

Comment: I will, thanks for your help today.